# Stop event from destroying created DIV when DIV is hovered on

Tags: javascript

I have "mouseover" event listener to HTML link. When this event is triggered (so mouse is over the link), there is `div` created. Then, I have another "mouseout" event listener to the link. When this second event is triggered (so mouse is out from the link), `outerHTML` of created `div` is set to empty so it disappears.

Now I need to make created `div` doesn't disappear when the mouse is hover on the created `div`. And then, when the mouse is out from the created `div`, it needs to disappear.

How do I do that in pure JavaScript?

Here's my code:

```
<a id="some_link" href="#">Some link</a>

<script>

    var link = document.getElementById("some_link");

    link.addEventListener("mouseover", onMouseOver);
    link.addEventListener("mouseout", onMouseOut);

    function onMouseOver(){

        newDiv = document.createElement("div");

        newDiv.id = "created_div";
        newDiv.innerHTML = "Created div";

        document.body.append(newDiv);

    }

    function onMouseOut(){

        var newDiv = document.getElementById("created_div");

        setTimeout(function(){
            newDiv.outerHTML = "";
        }, 200);

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Yeesh... Can you provide any relevant [mcve]?

Comment: Please provide more details, HTML or something to describe

Comment: yes, sorry, I did

Comment: You probably want to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, otherwise `mouseout` followed by an immediate `mouseover` will trigger when you enter or exit a nested element within the target element: https://jsfiddle.net/s6L6p8sk/

Comment: Actually, this would be easier with CSS.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I'm not sure If I understand you, but my two divs are not nested. When I use mouseenter and mouseleave it doesn't make any change

Comment: If your divs ever contain anything else besides a text node, you'll start having issues.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts actually it's an HTML link, I just used "div" as an example